# C programming and Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, vi, system

I am currently enrolled in a C systems programming course, I want to use Xcode (instead of vi). What type of project do I create when I open Xcode?

Comment: I don't have my Mac environment here to look at the specifics, but basically you just create a project for a stand-alone Mac application.

Comment: I guess it'd be classified as Mac OS X -> Command line tool? Though I'm wondering why you would want to use XCode. Personally, I prefer the CLI and Makefiles instead of an IDE for C code since I have more control. Having to deal with an IDE is just too annoying (for small projects).

Comment: How is this question not clear? He wants to use C in xCode, how much more programming-related can you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want **Command Line Utility** > **Standard Tool**.  This will give you just the ordinary C environment you get on every other OS.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X > Application > Command Line Tool. But I suspect you'd be be better off using `vi`, `emacs`, or something like `TextMate`. I'd guess that most C systems programming courses are going to use Makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

Open xcode 6,

Create new project (file menu, new, then project...

Then you'll see a screen "choose a template for your new project"

Choose command line tool.

That's it. You could google creating a command line tool in Xcode, how do I... if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to write C code, you want a command line tool application.